# Teamcity - how to watch a specific folder on a build agent, but keep access to .git?

Tags: teamcity

I currently have a VCS checkout rule that monitors a single folder inside a repo.

I need access to the .git folder in order to run some git commands as part of my build process.

I'm not an expert on teamcity, but my understanding is that these two requirements are conflicting:

- Monitoring a single folder via a VCS checkout rule requires that checkout is done on the server
- Checkout on the agent is required to guarantee that .git is created on the agent.

If possible, I would like to maintain the option to run on any build agent.

Is there an obvious way I can meet both requirements?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for your question ? I have the same issue with my configuration in TeamCity